# Ошибку синтаксиса JSON в консоли

Tags: javascript, json

Есть каталог товаров в JSON файле:

```
{
"11": {
    "name": "Green-Xtreame",
    "price": 250,
    "image" : "/image//tshirts.jpg"
},

"12": {
    "name": "Digital Owl",
    "price": 312,
    "image" : "/image//tshirt2.jpg"
},

"13": {
    "name": "I can",
    "price": 280,
    "image" : "/image//tshirt2.jpg"
},

"14": {
    "name": "Green-Xtreame",
    "price": 220,
    "image" : "/image//tshirts.jpg"
} 
}
```

Пытаюсь подключить его к JS И выводить данные по товарам (без jQuery):

```
function getJSONP(url, success) {
var ud = '_' + +new Date,
    script = document.createElement('script'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
           || document.documentElement;

window[ud] = function(data) {
    head.removeChild(script);
    success && success(data);
};

script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
head.appendChild(script);
}
getJSONP('file:///C:/Users/Task%203/work%20%E2%80/products.json', 
function(data){
var out = '';
    for (var key in data){
        out+='<div class="product">';
        out+='<h4>'+data[key]['name']+'</h4>';
        out+='<p> '+data[key]['price']+'</p>';
        out+='<img src="'+data[key].image+'">';
        out+='<button>Купить</button>';
        out+='</div>';

     getElementsById('products').html(out);
    }
 });
```

При проверке код не срабатывает, так как консоль выдает ошибку синтаксиса в json файле, хотя ошибок там нет. Подозреваю, что не удается распарсить json, как это можно решить?

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что json должен распарситься как jsonp?

Comment: так думаю потому, что он содержится в отдельном файле.
а есть другой путь доступиться к нему и вывести данные на страницу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что таким образом **нельзя** загружать json.

При добавлении `script`, идет попытка **выполнить** загружаемый код, так как json - это не корректный js код, то при попытке его выполнить получается ошибка.

---

Решений может быть несколько:

1. использовать локальный сервер, и делать обычные ajax запросы
2. поменять содержимое так, чтобы оно соответствовало требованиям к запросам JSONP, а именно, чтобы в файле был js код, который можно выполнить. Однако в этом случае нужно будет менять и код, который загружает, так как сейчас имя callback генерируется динамически ('_' + +new Date). В итоге код может выглядеть так:

   ```
   // main.js
   function callbackAjson(data) {
       var out = '';
       for (var key in data) {
           out += '<div class="product">';
           out += '<h4>' + data[key]['name'] + '</h4>';
           out += '<p> ' + data[key]['price'] + '</p>';
           out += '<img src="' + data[key].image + '">';
           out += '<button>Купить</button>';
           out += '</div>';

           document.getElementById('products').innerHTML = out;
       }
   }
   function getJSONP(url, success) {
       script = document.createElement('script'),
           head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
           || document.documentElement;
       script.src = url;
       head.appendChild(script);
   }
   getJSONP('a.json'); 
   // a.json
   callbackAjson({...}) // {...} - исходный Json
   ```

---

Кроме того, а обработчике сейчас допущены ряд ошибок, вроде опечатки в вызове `getElementById`, и попытке вызова у полученного элемента метода html, который остался от jQuery, вместо присваивания свойства innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

Какую ошибку выдает консоль?

```js
var text = `{
"11": {
    "name": "Green-Xtreame",
    "price": 250,
    "image" : "/image//tshirts.jpg"
},

"12": {
    "name": "Digital Owl",
    "price": 312,
    "image" : "/image//tshirt2.jpg"
},

"13": {
    "name": "I can",
    "price": 280,
    "image" : "/image//tshirt2.jpg"
},

"14": {
    "name": "Green-Xtreame",
    "price": 220,
    "image" : "/image//tshirts.jpg"
} 
}`;
var data = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: выдает "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "
и если перейти непосредственно к самому json, то это ошибка сразу после 
    {"11": {   , хотя все верно
присваивать переменную не совсем вариант, так как товаров будет добавлено много и хотелось бы держать их в отдельном файле, не включая в сам скрипт
можно ли так сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Пробуй задать тип файла
script.type = "application/json";

Comment: в этом случае не будет произведена загрузка файла.